# KeyError: <weakref at 0x7f37bb9587c0; to 'Flask' at 0x7f37be04ef20>

Tags: wtforms

I creating a Flask Application, use SQLite, SQLAlchemy and WTForms. My goal is to create Classification category tree to site users use HTML forms Like:
1 Category
1 Subcategory
2 subcategory
....
2 Category
....

I am having problems with WTForms **QuerySelectField** in my form (forma.validate_on_submit():).
After I open the form page, get errror:
**KeyError: <weakref at 0x7f37bb9587c0; to 'Flask' at 0x7f37be04ef20>**

Details 3 files:
**mainrun.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime
import formsrun
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'xxxxx'
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///todobudjet34.db"
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class CategoryGroup(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "category_group"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    category_group = db.Column(db.String(200), unique= True)
    category_add = db.relationship("MyCategory")

class MyCategory(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "mycategory"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    cat_gr_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('category_group.id'))
    my_category_name = db.Column(db.String(200), unique = True)
    my_sub_category_add = db.relationship("SubCategory")
    my_sub_directory_cat_add = db.relationship("SubDirectoryCat")

with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/categories")
def categories():
    try:
        categories = MyCategory.query.all()
    except:
        categories = []
    return render_template("categories.html", categories=categories)

@app.route("/newcategory", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def newcategory():
    db.create_all()
    forma = formsrun.CategoryForm()
    if forma.validate_on_submit():
        category = MyCategory(cat_gr_id=forma.category_group_source.data.id, my_category_name=forma.my_categ.data)
        db.session.add(category)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('categories'))

    return render_template("newcategory.html", form=forma)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8050, debug=True)
```

**formsrun.py**:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, IntegerField, SubmitField, SelectField, FloatField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Email, InputRequired
from wtforms_sqlalchemy.fields import QuerySelectField, QuerySelectMultipleField
import mainrun

def get_pk(obj):
    return str(obj)
def category_group_query():
    return mainrun.CategoryGroup.query

def category_query():
    return mainrun.MyCategory.query

class CategoryGroupForm(FlaskForm):
    my_category_group = StringField('My category group name', [DataRequired ()])
    submit = SubmitField("Enter")

class CategoryForm(FlaskForm):
    category_group_source = QuerySelectField(query_factory=category_group_query, get_label="category_group", get_pk=get_pk)
    my_categ = StringField('My category name', [DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField("Enter")
```

**newcategory.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %} {% block content %}

<form method="post" action="#">
  {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
  <div class="form-group">
    {{ form.category_group_source.label(class="form-control-label") }} {{
    form.category_group_source(class="form-control") }}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    {{ form.my_category.label(class="form-control-label") }} {{
    form.my_category(class="form-control") }}
  </div>
  {{ form.submit }}
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

I understand that the problem is here:
category = MyCategory(cat_gr_id=forma.category_group_source.data.id, my_category_name=forma.my_categ.data) in **mainrun.py**, and query_factory in **formsrun.py**

but unable to resolve this issue, Please help to solve this :)

Comment: What version of Flask and SQLAlchemy are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you upgraded to SQLAlchemy 3 but you are using the init routine of SQLAlchemy 2.

See https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/

> Changed in version 3.0: Engines are created when calling init_app
> rather than the first time they are accessed.

You need to call `db.init_app(app)`.

Comment: Thank You Daniel, yes i use Flask-SQLAlchemy   3.0.2, and  i change call too db.init_app(app) , but  I keep getting the same error :(

Comment: rather, not the same, but:
AssertionError: The setup method 'shell_context_processor' can no longer be called on the application. It has already handled its first request, any changes will not be applied consistently.
Make sure all imports, decorators, functions, etc. needed to set up the application are done before running it.

Comment: @Romzis I suspect you are not correctly initializing the whole app. The [manual](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/tutorial/factory/) says "The most straightforward way to create a Flask application is to create a global Flask instance directly at the top of your code, ... While this is simple and useful in some cases, it can cause some tricky issues as the project grows." I suspect you are running into few of those tricky issues.